# How to record last 20 activity in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working on a chatting project, but I found this problem that I am unable to solve.

Let's assume that I am a user named "Randy" and I have visited `foo1 , foo2, bar4, Teenagers,... count to 30` rooms.
Now I want to keep track of the last 20 rooms.

I was thinking that I could create a table just for keeping this kind of record and run a cron after some time for keeping only last 2 activity, OR I can create a row in user table where I will store last 20 record with some formatting like room1,room2

My question is which one is better for storing this kind of record? Or is there another method that can solve this problem more effectively?

Comment: Use [redis](http://redis.io). {grin}

Comment: Isn't redis a caching software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a visit table that has `FK` references to `user` table (`user_id`) , `room` table (`room_id`) and `timestamp`.

Of course you can clean up data once you have more than 30 rows per `user_id`